# Don't want bezier path get clipped by view frame

Tags: ios, swift

I thought that Bezier paths don't get clipped by the containing view, unless explicitly specified. I've verified in storyboard and can confirm that "Clip subviews" is unchecked. Also I've added `clipsToBounds = false`in `drawRect()`,

Is there a way to not clip the bezier path at edges of containing view?

I don't want to have a clipped circle like shown in the image:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 6
    let color: UIColor = UIColor.yellowColor()    
    clipsToBounds = false

    let haloRectFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height)
    let haloPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: haloRectFrame)
    haloPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
    color.set()
    haloPath.stroke()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've implemented two solutions. First solution utilises Bezier path with stroke. Here the stroke gets' clipped, so to fix it I've reduced the frame size. The second solution utilises CAShapeLayer, a subclass of CALayer. Here I use Bezier path, but since CAShapeLayer doesn't get clipped I don't need to reduce the frame size.

Solution 1 (Bezier path with stroke):

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let haloRectFrame = CGRectMake(
        lineWidth / 2,
        lineWidth / 2,
        rect.width - lineWidth,
        rect.height - lineWidth)

    let haloPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: haloRectFrame)
    haloPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
    color.set()
    haloPath.stroke()
}
```

Solution 2 (CAShapeLayer):

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let haloPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect).CGPath
    let haloLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: layer)
    haloLayer.path = haloPath
    haloLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    haloLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor
    haloLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    layer.addSublayer(haloLayer)
}
```